# Valor padrão em Select List .net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor

No meu sistema tenho um **select** que retorna os dados gravados em sua tabela do banco, o problema é que a lista já inicia com o primeiro registro automaticamente, e **preciso que ela retorne um texto padrão** e abaixo os dados da tabela para escolha, por exemplo "Selecionar", não sei como adicionar esse texto por padrão no meu select, segue os códigos:

cshtml:

```
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>PA</label>
      <select  class="form-control" id="PaId" asp-for="PaId" asp-items="ViewBag.PaId"></select>
      <span asp-validation-for="PaId" class="text-danger"></span>   
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult NovoChamado()
      {
          ViewData["PaId"] = new SelectList(_context.PAs,"PaId", "Nome");
          ViewData["FornecedorId"] = new SelectList(_context.Fornecedores, "FornecedorId","Empresa");
          ViewData["StatusId"] = new SelectList(_context.ChamadoStatus, "StatusId","Situacao");

          return View();
      }
```

[image: Exemplo do sistema, o primeiro texto gostaria que fosse selecionar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label>PA</label>
  <select  class="form-control" id="PaId" asp-for="PaId" asp-items="ViewBag.PaId">
    <option disabled selected>Selecionar...</option>
  </select>
  <span asp-validation-for="PaId" class="text-danger"></span>   
</div>
```

Você também pode no `backend` adicionar um item com o texto padrão que quer usar na sua lista, mas geralmente prefiro a forma acima.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado